# to avoid double click inside wrap function in html

Tags: html

I want to dial a number on a image click.. for this I have dynamically created div tags which contains such images. but I need to double click on image everytime to make a call.
I think it is happening because on  first click wrap function is called and on second click tel is being invoked. I want to make call on first click.please suggest an alternative for this.
My code is:

```
for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        var maindiv=document.createElement("div");
        maindiv.setAttribute("id", "maintablediv");
        var table=document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute("class","numbertable" );
        table.setAttribute("border",0);
        table.setAttribute("cellSpacing","0");
        table.setAttribute("cellPadding","0");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length ;
        var row =table.insertRow(rowCount);
        row.id="row";
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        if(i==0)
        {
            cell1.setAttribute("id","cmdcentralno");
        }
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        var p=document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML=desc[i];
        cell1.innerHTML=num[i];
        cell1.setAttribute("class","numbername");
        cell1.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        cell1.appendChild(p);
        cell2.setAttribute("class","phoneImg");
        var image=document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("src", "images/Icon-Phone-Green.png");
        if(i==0)
        {
            cell2.setAttribute("id","cmdcentralimage");
        }
        image.setAttribute("id", "imgphn"+i);

        image.className="imgphn";

       // var number=num[i].substring(num[i].indexOf('>')+1,num[i].indexOf('>')+14);

      image.setAttribute("name", dialnum[i]);
        cell2.appendChild(image);
        image.setAttribute("align","centre");
        maindiv.appendChild(table);
        document.getElementById("numberMenu").appendChild(maindiv);
        image.onclick=function()
        {
            var cellnumber=$(this).attr("name");
            $(this).wrap("<a href =tel:"+cellnumber+"/>");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I expect this should solve your problem...

```
    // move this outside of the click handler (and use `image` instead of `this`)
    image.wrap("<a href =tel:"+cellnumber+"/>");

    image.onclick=function()
    {
        var cellnumber=$(this).attr("name");
    }
```